# cakephp url not retrieving data

Tags: sql, cakephp

hi all when clicking the link on my page its not carrying the `id` from the `template` when going to the `view` page, so when the sql queries the database it is querying this

```
SELECT `Field`.`name`
FROM `pra`.`fields` AS `Field`
LEFT JOIN `pra`.`templates` AS `Template` ON (
    `Field`.`template_id` = `Template`.`id`)
WHERE `template`.`id` IS NULL
```

the database says id should be = `2`

here is the code for the view function

```
$fields = $this->Field->find('all',
           array('fields'=>array('name','template_id'),
                 'conditions' => array('template_id' =>  $this->Auth->user('template.id'))));

$this->set('field', $fields);
```

updated code, the template_id still equals null

when hardcoded it works correctly, there is a problem with this line `$this->Auth->user`

Comment: Have you checked what is the value of `$this->Auth->user('template_id')`?

Comment: when debugging that line I get null

Comment: Thats why you got the wrong result. The user who is currently logged in must have any template_id.

Comment: @arun-jain I was always under the assumption that 70% is ok: some questions don't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the result of the `find` call, by doing a `debug`:

```
debug($fields);
```

This will show you the returned data from the query. You can add this to the end of your action method.

If the results are empty, double check the values that are stored in the session Auth key. You can do this by dumping out the session with `debug($_SESSION)` or use the [CakePHP DebugKit](http://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit). The Debug Kit offers you a small toolbar at the top right of the screen and lets you view session information and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code:

```
$fields = $this->Field->find('all', 
           array('fields'=>array('name'),
                 'conditions' => array('Field.template_id' =>  $this->Auth->user('template_id'))
                 )
                            );

$this->set('field', $fields);
```

Please be sure there must have any `template_id` value should be there for the current logged in user.
Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\pra\app\Controller\FieldsController.php on line 35

Comment: page is loading but template_id is still null

Comment: doesn't print anything out, at all

Comment: still nothing, it may be because I'm changing controllers when I click the link, I'm going from the templates controller to fields/view/KiallaPersonalCustom, could that be why the template_id isnt working?

Comment: No, this is not the issue. Try with hardcoded "2" instead of `$this->Auth->user('template_id')` in find query and check the result.

Comment: i changed template_id to 2 and got nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
function view($name){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Template');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');
    $this->layout='home_layout';

$fields = $this->Template->Field->find('list',array( 
          'fields'=> array('name'),
          'conditions' => array(
          'template_id'=> $name)));
$this->set('field', $fields);


}
```

it wasn't passing the param's value